# Split a categorical column into columns with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Imagine a `pandas dataframe` of this shape

```
df

Age_group    Height  Weight 
Child        163      170
Adult        167      175
Old Adult    165      167
Child        175      170
Adult        180      165
```

I would like to have the dataframe in this shape

```
Child   Adult Old Adult  Height Weight 
1        0       0        163    170
0        1       0        167    175
0        0       1        165    167
1        0       0        175    170
0        1       0        180    165
```

Comment: Did you look at `pd.get_dummies()`? https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html

Answer (score 0):

You want to try [`pd.get_dummies()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html). In your case, this should work:

```
pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.Age_group)], axis=1)
```

Example:

```
In [0]: df = pd.DataFrame(["a", "b", "b", "c"], columns=["blop"])                                                                                                                      

In [1]: pd.concat([df, pd.get_dummies(df.blop)], axis=1)                                                                                                                               
Out[1]: 
  blop  a  b  c
0    a  1  0  0
1    b  0  1  0
2    b  0  1  0
3    c  0  0  1
```